# How to compare md5checksum of files in source server against destination servers in shell script?

Tags: linux, bash, shell, unix, md5sum

I have 100 files in `/data01/primary` folder and 100 different files in `/data02/secondary` folder in `machineX`. All these 200 files comes from `machineA` and `machineB` and if files are not there in `machineA`, then it should be there in `machineB` for sure.

So we are copying the files from `machineA` and `machineB` (which are source servers) to `machineX` (which is the destination server). And the files which we are copying from machineA and machineB is in this directory `/checkbat/data/snapshot/20140918` so we have this directory in both the source servers.

Now I am trying to do a md5 checksum on those 200 files which are in machineX by comparing it with machineA and machineB.

File path is like this, as you can see everything is same apart from 1, 2, 3, 4 numbers.

```
t1_monthly_1980_1_200003_5.data
t1_monthly_1980_2_200003_5.data
t1_monthly_1980_3_200003_5.data
t1_monthly_1980_4_200003_5.data
```

So there will be 100 files like above in /data01/primary folder and 100 different files in /data02/secondary folder in machineX which comes from machineA and machineB.

Now what I need to do is, compare the md5checksum of 100 files in `/data01/primary` folder with files in `machineA` and `machineB`. If any of the file checksum is different in source server as compare to destination servers, print out the file name and its checksum both on source and destination servers.

```
#!/bin/bash

export PRIMARY=/data01/primary
export SECONDARY=/data02/secondary

readonly DESTINATION_SERVER=(machineA machineB)
export DESTINATION_SERVER_1=${DESTINATION_SERVER[0]}
export DESTINATION_SERVER_2=${DESTINATION_SERVER[1]}

export FILES_LOCATION_ON_DESTINATION=/checkbat/data/snapshot/20140918

readonly SOURCE_SERVER=machineX

export dir3=$FILES_LOCATION_ON_DESTINATION

# compare the checksum and find the files whose checksum are different

for entry in "$PRIMARY"/*
do
    echo "$entry"
    # now how to compare the file checksum of this file with same file in machineA or machineB
done
```

I know how to do the md5checksum on a single file but not sure how to compare the file checksum over the network? Is this possible to do?

```
md5sum filename
```

I have setup my ssh everything and I can do ssh on those destination servers from my source server as `abc` user.

```
ssh abc@${DESTINATION_SERVER[0]}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use ssh to perform this task.

```
$ ssh user@hostname "/usr/bin/md5sum filename"
a40bd6fe1ae2c03addba2473e0bdc63b  filename
```

and if you want to automate tasks then assign it to a variable like this.

```
remote_md5sum=`ssh user@hostname  "/usr/bin/md5sum filename"`
```

Then you can use the value in $remote_md5sum for validating it works.

BTW, I use private key authentication in this scenario which makes it so I don't need a password.
    #!/bin/bash

```
export PRIMARY=/data01/primary
export SECONDARY=/data02/secondary

readonly DESTINATION_SERVERS=(machineA machineB)
export DESTINATION_SERVER_1=${DESTINATION_SERVERS[0]}
export DESTINATION_SERVER_2=${DESTINATION_SERVERS[1]}

export FILES_LOCATION_ON_DESTINATION=/checkbat/data/snapshot/20140918

readonly SOURCE_SERVER=machineX

export dir3=$FILES_LOCATION_ON_DESTINATION

# compare the checksum and find the files whose checksum are different

for entry in "$PRIMARY"/*
do
    local_md5sum=`/usr/bin/md5sum "$entry" | awk '{print $1}'`

        for DESTINATION_SERVER in $DESTINATION_SERVERS
        do
                remote_md5sum=`ssh user@$DESTINATION_SERVER /usr/bin/md5sum "$entry" | awk '{print $1}'`

                # now how to compare the file checksum of this file with same file in machineA or machineB
                if [ "$local_md5sum" -eq "$remote_md5sum" ] 
                then
                        echo "match";
                else
                        echo "not match"
                fi
        done
done
```

Comment: I already have setup ssh everything as user `abc` but not sure how can I do everything in a single shell script.

Comment: Thanks for example. I was trying your suggestion and I added `echo local_md5sum` and ran it but it didn't printed out anything on the console. Do you know what could be the reason?

Comment: try executing /usr/bin/md5sum filename | awk '{print $1}' and if that doesn't work then verify that /usr/bin/md5sum exists. or it might have been a typo in my script that I just updated. DESTINATION_SERVER vs destination_server